# Metrics to compare XML and JSON

Tags: iphone, xml, json

I am looking for more metrics that i can use to compare XML and JSON in iPhone applications using Apple's libraries. As of now i am doing the following

- serialization and deserialization speed
- Energy Consumption
- Memory Usage
- CPU Usage

Are there more metrics i can use to compare the two.

Note: Metrics need to be testable. I can't include size because its apparent that XML will always be larger than JSON irrespective of environment.

Comment: So, what have you measured?

Comment: I haven't really started working on it. But i am still building all the stuff that i am going to do. I will be using "Instruments" for profiling and getting test result data.